# Optimize web page for mobile

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I am trying to get my webpage to show zoomed in when the user browses to it.  The whole page should only be 320px wide aligned left all the content in one column.  but when I go to the page the site does not look good until the viewer taps on the screen to zoom and even then they can scroll horizontally (and see nothing)

**How can I auto zoom the page?**

Should I align center everything?

my css and html is below:

```
* {

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

}
body.body_sp{background-image:url(../images/content_sp.jpg);background-repeat:repeat-x;background-repeat:repeat-y;width:320px;}
#head_sp{width:320px;height:127px;}
#content_sp{width:320px;}
#footer_sp{width:320px;}

h1.sp_h1{margin:10px 0 20px 5px;text-align:left;}
p.sp_p{margin:20px;letter-spacing:.5px;line-height:16px;font:13px arial;}
p.sp_p a{color:red;}
```

you can see my html here  http://patriotsar.com/patriot_droid.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these to your < head >

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/> 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: I did have it set. Sorry the code above must have been when I took it out to test. I will edit it back in.